# In Lua, how do I get New York time when considering daylight saving time?

Tags: datetime, lua, timezone

I am trying to get New York time (which is different than my local time) by following code in Lua:

```
local utc_t = os.date("!*t", os.time())
local tzoffset = -1 * 5 * 60 * 60   -- EST is -05:00 from UTC
local est_t = os.date("*t", os.time(utc_t) + tzoffset)
```

However, for New York, there is daylight saving time (& the dates to enter/exit daylight saving time are different each year).

When it's in daylight saving time, it's EDT (-04:00 from UTC).

Is there any way I can get the correct New York time at any given time in any local timezone?

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/TimeZone

Comment: thanks for the link (I have saw it earlier because I have tried to google & research about my question). However, the link cannot answer my question. It's kind of different.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `luatz` library. Specifically, use the function `time_in(timezone_name)`.

You can either install it as a rock or grab the source. See https://rocks.moonscript.org/modules/daurnimator/luatz for further information.

Comment: the lib seems getting timezone info from "/usr/share/zoneinfo/"? Is there any native Lua method?

Comment: Perhaps you can do something with `os.execute` and manipulate the `TZ` and related environment variables. But I don't think that's a productive approach.

Comment: Another thought: all the files in luatz *are* native Lua. If the external dependency on the tz database is a problem, you could hardcode the New York timezone info in your Lua code.